# Factor a square matrix ${\bf A}$ into product ${\bf B}{\bf C}$, where ${\bf C}$ has no negative entries

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

*A more carefully worded version of this question, for professional mathematicians, appears [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234881/factor-matrix-bf-a-into-the-product-bf-b-bf-c-where-bf-c-has-no).*

Consider a general $n \times n$ matrix ${\bf A}$ with possibly positive and negative entries.  Is there an algorithm to write this matrix as a product of two $n \times n$ matrices, i.e., ${\bf A} = {\bf B}{\bf C}$, in which all the entries of ${\bf C}$ are non-negative?

*Polar decomposition*--in which ${\bf B}$ is unitary and ${\bf C}$ is positive semi-definite Hermitian--is closely related to this question but does not quite solve it.  Likewise *positive matrix factorization* (which assume ${\bf A}$ itself has only non-negative entries) does not quite solve it.  Nor does *Cholesky decomposition*, for related reasons.

Of course, the trivial solution ${\bf B} = {\bf A}$ and ${\bf C} = {\bf I}$ (the identity matrix) will yield such a factorization.  So will trivial rescalings of that solution.  (However, if all the entries of ${\bf A}$ are non-negative then the algorithm should return the solution ${\bf B} = {\bf I}$ and ${\bf C} = {\bf A}$.)

Hence we need a condition or merit function or constraint to make the problem well-posed.  As you can see from the below discussion, the ideal metric is one in which the number of non-zero multiplications is large due to ${\bf C}$ (low computational cost) and which is small due to ${\bf B}$ (high computational cost).  In short, the ideal metric is large number of (positive) entries in ${\bf C}$ and small number of (positive and negative) entries in ${\bf B}$.

I do not need an algorithm to find a *unique* decomposition, just a principled method for finding at least *one*.

**Motivation**

Suppose some computational system can perform a matrix multiplication at extremely low cost only if every component matrix multiplication is of two non-negative real numbers.  Then if we can put as much of the overall computation of ${\bf A}{\bf x}$ (where ${\bf x}$ is a vector of non-negative entries) into the ${\bf C}{\bf x}$, then the overall cost will be low.

Comment: Just to comment my little thoughts about this.
1- Maximizing the Frobenius norm of $C$ is a bad idea, as you can always take $A = (\lambda A)  (\lambda^{-1} I)$.
2- You can make appear as many fundamental matrices $E$ in between $B$ and $C$, i.e. $A=BEE^{-1}C$, with this method and keeping as invariant that the right hand side has positive coefficients, you could design an algorithm, thou this does not reach all the possible decompositions (all right hand matrices C you would get would be invertible, but not necessarily you can reach all the positive invertible matrices).

Comment: Francisco:  You are right... the Frobenius norm is not quite the right metric.  As should be clear from my **Motivation**, the true metric should involve the total number of non-zero multiplications due to ${\bf C}$ (high is good) versus those due to ${\bf B}$ (low is good).  But this is an awkward metric, mathematically.  I'll edit my question, however.  I'm not worried that I reach *all* decompositions, just a principled method to find at least *one*.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Initialize B and C with random values from the uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$. The objective is to use gradient descent to minimize $||A - B(C^2)||^2_F$ (Frobenius norm), where $C^2$ is element-wise squaring, not the matrix product of $C$ with itself. When gradient descent finishes, you can factor A with $A = B(C^2)$, where again $C^2$ is element-wise squaring of the entries in $C$.